# Is the equation for the area bounded by a curve unique?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

The area of $D$ that is bounded by the closed curve $C$ given parametrically by $x=x(t)$ and $y=y(t)$ is $$\frac{1}{2}\int_Cx\,dy-y\,dx.\tag{1}$$

It seems obvious (this naivete may  may be incorrect) that (1) pops out of the equation for the area of $D$, $\int\int_D1dxdy$, when applying Green's theorem to it:

$$\int\int_D1\,dx\,dy=\int\int_D\left(\frac{\partial F_y}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial F_x}{\partial y}\right)\,dx\,dy=\int_CF_y\,dy+F_x\,dx$$

$$\frac{\partial F_y}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial F_x}{\partial y}=1.\tag{2}$$

But isn't $F_y=\frac{1}{2}x$ and  $F_x=-\frac{1}{2}y$ just one of the infinite solutions to equation (2), giving a different equation (1)?

This would imply, for example, that $\frac{1}{2}\int_Cx\,dy-y\,dx=\int_C 2x\,dy+y\,dx$ ($F_y=2x$ and  $F_x=y$), which *looks* false (is it?).

Comment: You shouldn't write of "infinite solutions" if you mean "infinitely many solutions".  "Infinite solutions" means "solutions, each one of which, by itself, is infinite".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That sounds right. But your last equation is *not* false, because $\int_C xdy+ydx$ is always zero, so you can add or subtract any multiple of it to the integral without changing its value.

This is again because $\int_C xdy$ and $\int_C (-y)dx$ are both expressions for the *same* area of $D$, so their difference must vanish.

The "canonical" $\frac12 \int_C xdy-ydx$ can be understood as the limit of successive polygonal approximations to $D$, computed by the [shoelace formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoelace_formula). $\int_C xdy$ and $\int_C (-y)dx$ as the area between the curve and one of the coordinate axes, with sign depending on whether the curve is moving up or down (so the parts of the areas *outside* the closed curve cancel out).